# Clang static analysis with MPI

Tags: c++, clang, mpi, static-analysis, clang++

I would like to use [Clang's static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) for analyzing parallel code, i.e., code with needs MPI compiler wrappers.
When configuring with CMake, however, I always get

```
$ scan-build cmake /path/to/source
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/share/clang/scan-build/c++-analyzer
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/share/clang/scan-build/c++-analyzer -- works
```

and the subsequent compilation (`make`) fails with

```
/usr/include/some/header.hpp:56:17: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
```

#include "mpi.h"

How to properly use `scan-build` here?

Comment: Did you try exporting CFLAGS='-I/path/to/mpi.h'?

Answer (score 3):

I have not found a way to use the MPI compiler wrappers directly with `scan-build`. You can however circumvent the wrappers and give the flags to your compiler manually. e.g. this works for my environment:

```
$ export CXXFLAGS=`mpicxx --showme:compile`
$ export LDFLAGS=`mpicxx --showme:link`
$ export CXX=`mpicxx --showme:command`
$ scan-build ./configure && scan-build make #Or your cmake equivalent
```

The `--showme:` flags seem to differ slightly between versions, but `mpicc --showme:help` usually gives you a list of commands your specific wrapper supports.

Answer (score 1):

See [MPI-Checker/examples](https://github.com/0ax1/MPI-Checker/tree/master/examples) :

> To invoke the Clang Static Analyzer, it is recommended to use the
>   [scan-build](https://github.com/rizsotto/scan-build) package implemented in Python. You can either use the
>   scripts being contained in LLVM trunk
>   (`llvm/tools/clang/tools/scan-build-py/bin`) or install the scripts
>   with `pip install scan-build`. Note that on make install LLVM copies old
>   Perl versions of the scripts to `/usr/local/bin` which therefore might
>   overwrite versions installed with pip.
>
> As the MPI wrapper compiler interferes with the scan-build script, it
>   is recommended to invoke the analysis based on a compilation database,
>   generated by `intercept-build (make|ninja|...)`. Note that databases
>   generated by CMake can differ from those generated by intercept-build.
>   If the compile_commands.json file denotes mpicc|mpic++ as the used
>   compiler, no reports are emitted.
>
> After the compilation database is created, analysis can be triggered
>   with:
>  `analyze-build --enable-checker your.check --use-analyzer /path/to/clang`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a MPI wrapper for your c-compiler. Which means a MPI library compiled with CLang. After you got that, you need to set the c compiler in your build environment to mpicc. This should provide you with correct includes and linking options.